# Regex, English to Pig Latin - how to fix capitalization

Tags: regex, elixir, pcre

**Edit:** the original question was off topic, editing to correct.

I'm working through some coding challenges learning Elixir and came across one to translate English into [Pig Latin on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin).

I started working out regex for different rules and realized doing it all in one shouldn't be that difficult.  After playing with it a little I've arrived at the following to match and convert a single word at a time.

Elixir is supposed to use PCRE compatible regex but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get `\u` [one character to upper](https://regular-expressions.mobi/replacecase.html) and `\L` [All characters to lower](https://regular-expressions.mobi/replacecase.html) to work in elixir string replacement. I've tried several variations of working those into the replacement string but am completely failing to find a way that works.

Is there a way using pure Regex in elixir String.replace it do I need to just handle the rest in regular code?

```
iex(21)> regex = ~r/(^(?:[aeiouAEIOU]|[XYxy][^aeiouy])(?:.*))|(?:^([A-Z][^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))|(?:^([^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))/
~r/(^(?:[aeiouAEIOU]|[XYxy][^aeiouy])(?:.*))|(?:^([A-Z][^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))|(?:^([^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))/
iex(22)> String.replace("Squirl", regex, "\\1\\u\\3\\L2\\5\\4ay")
"\\uirl\\L2ay"
iex(23)> String.replace("Squirl", regex, "\\1\\3\\2\\5\\4ay")
"irlSquay"
```

**Original question below:**

One note the challenge I'm completely says words that start with a vowel just append 'ay' to the end. Some other instructions say "way" or "yay"

Powershell version:

```
[Regex]$reg = '(^(?:[aeiou]|[xy][^aeiouy])(?:.*))|(?:^([^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))'
'powershell' -replace $reg, ('$1$3$2' + 'ay')
```

Elixir version:

```
regex = ~r/(^(?:[aeiou]|[xy][^aeiouy])(?:.*))|(?:^([^aeiou]*(?:u)?)([aeiouy].*))/i
String.replace("elixir", regex, "\\1\\3\\2ay")
```

This seems to easy, are there the cases I'm missing?

Comment: `Latin` goes to `Atinlay` not `atinLay`; `yule` goes to `yuleay` and `honest` goes to `honestay` (but `happy` goes to `appyhay`)

Comment: Hmm I haven't messed with changing case in a regex, that sounds like an interesting challenge.  Is there a way to figure out words like yule, and honest without doing a dictionary lookup to find the phonetic pronunciation?

Comment: You are missing “naïve” for instance. Also, this is an offtopic on this site, you’d better post it somewhere on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or like.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for commenting, I didn't realize there was a code review site. I'm not sure how to move a post though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [elixir regex](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Regex.html) documentation, you can see it is based on erlang's [`:re`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) which clearly states:

> The matching algorithms of the library are based on the PCRE library, but not all of the PCRE library is interfaced

And then:

> #### Unsupported Escape Sequences
>
> In Perl, the sequences \l, \L, \u, and \U are recognized by its string handler and used to modify the case of following characters. PCRE does not support these escape sequences.

---

#### Workaround

You have to use [`String.replace`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/String.html#replace/4) with "a function that receives the matched pattern and must return the replacement as a string or iodata" as the `replacement` (third) parameter.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, sorry I don't know where to go to trace out all that